# how to close first screen after open second screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation`.

I have a `stackNavigation` like this:

```
export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Splash: {
    screen: Splash,
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
  Options: {
    screen: Options,
  },
},);
```

at the first time, `Splash` screen opened and I use this code to run `Home` screen:

Splash:

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

when `Home` screen is opened I want to close `Splash` screen. but when I use back button on my android device, it shows `Splash` screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the navigation index before to navigate to the 'Home' page, with the `reset()` function from `StackActions`. In this way, the page you are navigating to becomes the new root of the app. Here is the example from the doc :

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

See the doc : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in simple way. use replace instead of navigate

```
this.props.navigation.replace('Home');
```